# scp recursive command for local to remote copy

Tags: linux, scp, cp

So, I have been doing some `scp` stuff recently from my local machine to my server, and today, by `mistake`, I excecuted the following:

```
scp -r myfolder foo@192.254.96:/home/myhome .
```

What I meant to do was to copy `myfolder` from my local machine to my remote, but I had forgot to set the folder and used `.` at the end by mistake.

Now, the first output I got was:

```
cp: `myfolder' and `./myfolder' are the same file
```

and then, it went on to transfer a range a files ( a lot of them).

Now, I am totally clueless what happened - and where the transferred files are.

Not that this is of any concern i.e in terms of security etc, but I am trying to learn here what really happened when I used:

```
scp -r myfolder foo@192.254.96:/home/myhome .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is the current folder. The command above copied the folders `myfolder` and `foo@192.254.96:/home/myhome` into the current folder, hence the error message that you tried to copy `myfolder` to `myfolder`.

I'm a bit surprised that `scp` didn't stop after the error. Since it didn't, you'll find a new folder `myhome` next to `myfolder` with files from your server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Aaron - I learnt something here. I was also a bit surprised that `scp` did not stop, but again, was my mistake. I now find the files as you have said (my home is a bit crowded!) under `myhome` which is next to `myfolder` with files from my server. Thanks again - accepted your answer.